# How do i hear my microphone?

Tags: microphone

I just got some headphones with a microphone. I want test the microphone.
But, the problem is how can I hear what I say in microphone in my headphones. Thank you guys. I hope you will help me, to solve this problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can install "*Sound Recorder*" from the Ubuntu Software Center.  (Or, to install using the command line, simply type `sudo apt-get install gnome-media` in a terminal window).  This program will let you record sound snippets and play them back.  After installing, search for "*Sound Recorder*" in the Unity Dash to launch it.

To control or set your audio inputs and outputs, you can install "*PulseAudio Volume Control*" from the Ubuntu Software Center.  (Or, to install using the command line, simply type `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` in a terminal window).  This program will let you configure or select Playback, Recording, Output Devices, or Input Devices.  After installing, search for "*PulseAudio Volume Control*" in the Unity Dash to launch it.

In "*PulseAudio Volume Control,*" if you navigate to the Input Devices tab, you can tap on your microphone and see the volume meeter jump.  If the volume meter does not jump, set the correct microphone from the Port drop-down on this tab.

Finally you can also run "*PulseAudio Volume Meter (Capture)*" from the Unity Dash as you record something (or use your microphone) to see a simple microphone volume meter as you speak.  Note that two programs, "*PulseAudio Volume Meter (Capture)*" and "*PulseAudio Volume Meter (Playback)*" are also installed automatically along with "*PulseAudio Volume Control.*"